# How to use enum instead of three different states?

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement, enums, boolean

I have three states for two booleans:

```
_shouldViewMoveUp = true
_shouldViewMoveDown = false

_shouldViewMoveUp = false
_shouldViewMoveDown = false

_shouldViewMoveUp = false
_shouldViewMoveDown = true
```

We need to track for both boolean variables wether is false/true when there is changes in the keyword frame. I want to design my code to look better.

I'm not sure how to do it with enum or one boolean. Can you explain how I can make my code tidy or just the way it is right?

Comment: Just as a tip, you might find that http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is more appropriate for questions where the code works but could be improved.

Comment: @AdrianWragg Not for snippets of code. CR is really for full code.

Comment: @easterlyirk Will bear that in mind; I just looked at a few questions and they seemed to contain snippets, didn't look in depth.

Comment: @AdrianWragg snippet of a project yes, but not a couple lines demonstrating an idea.  It kinda needs to do something by itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Define the `enum` in the header:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, MoveDirection) {
    MOVE_NOWHERE,
    MOVE_UP,
    MOVE_DOWN
};
```

then simply use it where you would use any other primitive; for example:

```
- (void)moveInDirection:(MoveDirection)direction
{
    switch (direction) {
        case MOVE_UP:
             // move up
             break;
        case MOVE_DOWN:
             // move down
             break;
        default:
             break;
    }
}
```

or:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) MoveDirection moveDirection;
```

Comment: Is it too bad to have two booleans? I want to know also which one is cleaner?

Comment: @Bernard An `enum` will be much cleaner.  As you can see you can implement the no-move, move-up and move-down logic in a simple `switch` statement where as using two `BOOL`s would require more complicated `if`/`else` statements.  It's also impossible to set an invalid condition; for example what does it mean to set both `_shouldViewMoveUp` and `_shouldViewMoveDown` to `YES`?

Comment: Use `NS_ENUM` please.

Comment: @Sulthan What is the difference?

Comment: @Sulthan I generally shy away from `NS_ENUM` unless I care about the storage size, which is rare.  I believe the point is made, and the values can be defined using `typedef enum` or `NS_ENUM` as the OP prefers.

Comment: `NS_ENUM` has additional compiler/analyzer warnings in LLVM. Also, plain C enums don't work with Swift.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSNumber` for storing direction.

Fox example:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSNumber *movedDown;


if (nil == self.movedDown) {
// not moved anywhere
} else if (self.movedDown.boolValue) {
// is moved down
} else {
// is moved up
}
```

when moved, you assign `@YES` or `@NO`

when not moved: `nil`